# Are orgnizations like European Association for Psychotherapy (EAP) or European Family Therapy Association (EFTA) genuine?

Tags: psychology, training

My sibling mentioned me about her idea of pursuing a additional post-university training for obtaining an [EAP](https://www.europsyche.org/) and [EFTA](http://www.europeanfamilytherapy.eu/) compliant certificate for psychotherapy.

I raised a question regarding the credibility of such programs, which visibly made her feel uneasy.

I have a technical background, and scam and pay per publish conferences and journals are very common in my field, and given my experience I can easily tell what a scam is in my field. However, my sister has little experience in her field, i.e., psychology, so I would like to make sure that she does not take the wrong path. The price of the course that she mentioned was over $3000 for a 4 year training.

In short: are EAP and EFTA trainings genuine? What is the worth of their certification programs in the field?

---

*Note:* I apologize if this question is inappropriate to anyone who might be associated to those organizations, but as I said, my background knowledge is very limited, but at the same time I want to be a helpful bro.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. What country are you talking about?  Some countries have different requirements to others

Comment: I also would say that $3000 us extremely cheap for a 4 year course in psychotherapy and would wonder how rigorous the course would be.  Whilst waiting for your response on the country, I will be trying to look at their training structure.

Comment: Even if those organizations are genuine (which they seem to be) that doesn't mean a given training program is. For example, IEEE is definitely a legit organization within EE and CS, but there are lots of predatory conferences and such that dubiously present themselves as affiliated with IEEE, especially in countries like India from what I've seen on Academia.SE.

Comment: For example the EAP's European Certificate for Psychotherapy states "The total duration of the training will not be less than 3200 hours, spread over a minimum
of seven years, with the first three years being the equivalent of a relevant university degree. The later four years of which must be in a training specific to psychotherapy. The EAP will, in collaboration with NAOs and EWAOs, determine the proportion of the training elements that need to be completed prior to the ECP being awarded."

Comment: I can't imagine that being as cheap as that, in the US where education is stupidly expensive, but I could imagine a 4 year course of psychotherapy study costing the student only $3000 out of pocket *if subsidized by the state* and through a reputable institution.

Comment: I am voting to close this question due to the fact that there is not enough information to answer the question adequately despite being asked for the information required